# how avoid QUERY_LIMIT rate in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I have a database that has a lot of poorly formatted addresses. In this addresses, I have an only street address or street with the city name. In my application user choose some category and after I want to show for example 50,100,300 etc. addresses on map.(not all addresses from my database but a small piece of data).

So my question is, what is the best practice to geocode this addresses to lat long in my case?

I read a lot of about google geocoding and there is a QUERY_LIMIT

2,500 free requests per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

50 requests per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
So I think that I could store my data in applications cache and geocode addresses using Geocoding API web service.

For example, user set category and after it application sends a request for geocoding and after this is saved in, for example, shared preferences, and when the user again set this category application search for addresses in shared preferences and if applications don't find anything then make a query.

But Google has 50-requests per second limit, so if many users at the same time send a request there will be a problem and they get QUERY_LIMIT.

Is my thinking good? Or does this affect IP and this problem will not occur? Or maybe I should use another API to geocode an address, not from google? What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a requests distributor which have a queue for geocoding requests and monitor the timing so that you won't hit the limits (this could increase the response time for users in peak hours).

I would also recommend storing the response in your database for further usage and have a background process which send geocoding requests for popular addresses automatically so you have the maximum allowed daily requests used.

Comment: I would only add that Google allows temporary cache for 30 days, so you should refresh the temporary storage periodically. For more details look at section 10.5 (d) of Terms of Service: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?#section_10_5